# Search "if condition" in .java file

Tags: java, regex

I want to search all `if conditions` in `.java` file.

I am using `BufferedReader` to read file and pattern to search condition.

My program searching all `if` but when my file look this:

// if{}

I get bad result.

I want to get only valid if conditions (also `if{}` and `if {}` - between `if` and `{` is space), without conditions in comments.

How should it look `regex`?

Full code: http://pastebin.com/55RMfwg2

Comment: I think your problem is too complex to be solved with a single regular expression.  Given your problem with '// if{}', what if you run into an if condition in the middle of a /*...*/ comment block?  The regular expression will not be able to differentiate that line.  You may need to use a full Java parser.

Comment: I suggest cleaning a file first (delete new lines, multiple whitespaces, comments etc.) and then it's gonna be easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^(?!a\\/\\/) *if *\\{(.|\n)*}
```

This regex will look for if without // before it and with optional space after it,
it will also catch the closing bracket `}` and allow new line character between the brackets.
Moreover it will accept spaces before the if.

If multi-line comments `/* */` should be skipped also, I think as other people wrote, it will be easier to just clean the file before.

There are many websites that can help you to find the exact regex, i will recommend [RegExr](http://regexr.com/).

Comment: { is an indicator to the regex engine that you are about to start a repetition indicator, you should escape it with \\

Comment: Okay, it work. But in "ifif" found 2 conditions, hot modify regex?